# How to remove the world border in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like a world where I can travel to the *old* Minecraft world limits (2^31-1 blocks) in Minecraft 1.20+.

I'm open to using mods to make this happen.
All blocks should be accessible in survival at all times.

How do I configure a world like this in Minecraft 1.20+?

Comment: are you talking about the far lands? or are you talking about just an *actual* infinite world?

Comment: well, not infinite, but just to +/-2billion

Comment: @Tiimzy Throughout the Minecraft version history, there have been various buggy effects at high coordinates, not just farlands. This pretty much ended in 1.8 with the world border.

Comment: Oh OK, so your saying that there are buggy effects ***after*** you go through the border? If so, then sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: @Tiimzy they added the border to *prevent* those issues.

Comment: Leaving a note about https://github.com/PercyDan54/BorderRemover here - I'm gonna investigate this when I'm home in about three hours and check if it works on 1.20/whether it works at all. It's not on CurseForge or Modrinth so I'm mildly skeptical. Will post as an answer if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find a mod. It does work, but it's clear there's a reason why the world border limits things to 30 million. It doesn't handle shadows well beyond that point, as shown in the image below - and on further testing, **Minecraft will teleport you and every entity loaded beyond where the world border would be to that location upon saving and reloading the world**.

[image: An image of a 1.20.4 modded Minecraft world with coordinates reading "900000156, 65, 899999990" and displaying the errors with shadows that occur at that distance.]

[image: An image of the same world with coordinates now reading "30000511, 72, 30000512" and showing a large number of mobs stacked in the same location.]

You can see the GitHub page [here](https://github.com/PercyDan54/BorderRemover) and download it [on the Releases section](https://github.com/PercyDan54/BorderRemover/releases/tag/1.0.7), if you still want to download it despite knowing this. While it claims to be for 1.19, it works on 1.20 too.